# Do 7bit and 8bit encoded messages have to be decoded before outputting?

Tags: php, encoding, imap

What's the possible relation between 7bit transfer encoding and UTF-7, as well as between 8bit and UTF-8 ?

Does it make sense manually converting message body encoding to expected one (assume 'utf-8') as in the code below ?

```
 function decodeBody($body, $transferEncoding, $bodyEncoding) {

        switch ($transferEncoding) { 

            case '7BIT' :
            case '8BIT' :   
                                    // any additional decoding here ?
                $body = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'utf-8', $bodyEncoding);
            break;


            case 'BASE64' :
                $body = base64_decode($body);
                $body = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'utf-8', $bodyEncoding);
            break;

            case 'QUOTED_PRINTABLE' :
                $body = quoted_printable_decode($body);
                $body = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'utf-8', $bodyEncoding);
            break;

        }

        return $body;
    }
```

Comment: something you may want to read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html `Quote:There's something called UTF-7, which is a lot like UTF-8 but guarantees that the high bit will always be zero`

Answer (score 3):

Citing the [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html):

**The values "8bit", "7bit", and "binary" all imply that NO encoding has been performed...
"8bit" means that the lines are short, but there may be non-ASCII characters (octets with the high-order bit set).**

This means that 7bit is pure ascii and you don't need to convert it to UTF-8 at all (so no need to use `mb_convert_encoding()` in that case). '8bit' means that non-ascii characters might be present, but as far as I understand it need not necessarily be in UTF-8 charset encoding - might be iso-8859-1 or whatever as well. So AFAIK '8bit' doesn't mean UTF-8 automatically.

Comment: i'm not shure if this is the answer i'm looking for: the 7bit encoding means that an 8bit character is encoded with "=F6" (for example). Thats of course an encoding that have to be decoded to print it to a website or something else.

Answer (score 0):

**No, No need to decoding**

According to RFC 822 the original SMTP protocol has been designed to transfer message in 7-bit format (original ASCII).

so any message has the 8th bit set to 1 should be encoded somehow.

**7-bit** means to encoding needed at all.

**8-bit** means it is a 8bit-clean message and the SMTP server didn't alter the message. it doesn't need decoding on the recipient end.
but if you want to send the message using SMTP, you have to encode it as '7bit' or 'quote-printable' (to not use the 8th bit on the message)

so you don't need this line at all:

```
$body = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'utf-8', $bodyEncoding);
```

but after decoding these encoding, according to RFC2047 there maybe some string in the message **body or even header** need to be **MIME Decode**, so you have to pass the string to that method if data is not a blob (not attachment file):

```
imap_utf8()
```